# React Context is not working as expected: Unable to ubdate the cartItems array and addProductToCart function isn't working

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jsx, react-context, react-component

So when I click add to cart on the shop page it should add the item to the cartItem' array nothing happens, also the cartItems array appears to be of type "never[]" and I don't know how to fix that in jsx.

[Project link on GitHub](https://github.com/OsamaHIma/Store/tree/main/clothing-store/src)

cart.context.jsx file

```
import { useState, createContext } from "react";

export const addCartItem = (cartItems, productToAdd) => {
  const existingCartItem = cartItems.find(
    (cartItem) => cartItem.id === productToAdd.id
  );

  if (existingCartItem) {
    return cartItems.map((cartItem) =>
      cartItem.id === productToAdd.id
        ? { ...cartItem, quantity: cartItem.quantity + 1 }
        : cartItem
    );
  }

  return [...cartItems, { ...productToAdd, quantity: 1 }];
};

export const CartContext = createContext({
  cartItems: [],
  addItemToCart: () => {},
});

export const CartProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([]);

  const addItemToCart = (product) => {
    setCartItems(addCartItem(cartItems, product));
  };

  const value = { addItemToCart, cartItems };
  return <CartContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</CartContext.Provider>;
};
```

cart.jsx file

```
import CartItem from "../components/cart-item";
import { toggleClass } from "./navigation";

import { useContext } from "react";
import { CartContext } from "../context/cart.context";

import "../scss/cart.scss";

const Cart = () => {
  const { cartItems } = useContext(CartContext);

  return (
    <div className={`card cart`} style={{ width: "18rem" }}>
      <button
        type="button"
        className="btn-close m-2"
        aria-label="Close"
        onClick={toggleClass}
      ></button>
      <div className="card-body text-center" style={{ height: "20rem" }}>
        <h5 className="card-title">Cart</h5>
        <div>
          {cartItems.length ? (
            cartItems.map((item) => <CartItem key={item.id} cartItem={item} />)
          ) : (
            <h5>The cart is empty</h5>
          )}
        </div>
        <button href="#" className="checkOutBtn mb-2 btn bg-dark text-white">
          Check Out
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Cart;
```

cart-item.jsx file

```
const CartItem = ({ item }) => {
  const {name, imageUrl, price, quantity } = item;
  return  (
    <div className="card mb-3">
      <div className="row g-0">
        <div>
          <div className="col-md-4">
            <img
              src={imageUrl}
              className="img-fluid rounded-start"
              alt={name}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-8">
            <div className="card-body">
              <h5 className="card-title">{name}</h5>
              <p className="card-text">{price}</p>
              <p className="card-text">{quantity}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CartItem;
```

productCart.jsx file

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import { CartContext } from "../context/cart.context";

const ProductCard = ({ product }) => {
  
  const { addItemToCart } = useContext(CartContext);
  const addProductToCart = () => addItemToCart(product);

  const { name, imageUrl, price } = product;

  return (
    <div className="col-md-3 my-2">
      <div className="card pb-3">
        <div
          className="image-container"
          style={{ height: "300px", overflow: "hidden" }}
        >
          <img src={imageUrl} className="card-img-top" alt={`${name}`} />
        </div>
        <div className="card-body d-flex justify-content-between">
          <p className="card-text d-inline">{name}</p>
          <span className="d-inline text-success">{price}$</span>
        </div>
        <button
          className="btn btn-success w-50 mx-auto"
          onClick={addProductToCart}
        >
          Add to cart
          <i className="fa fa-cart-plus mx-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I tried to call the addCartItem function from ProductCard and it worked and added the item to the array but the array didn't update so the cart component didn't render anything cause the array was empty.

Comment: Did you wrap your CartProvider?

Comment: Like that? <CartContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</CartContext.Provider>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NVM guys I found the problem  I  didn't set up the provider properly in the index.js

What should I've written

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <UserProvider>
    <ProductsProvider>
      <CartProvider>
        <App />
      </CartProvider>
    </ProductsProvider>
  </UserProvider>
</BrowserRouter>
```

> What I wrote

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <UserProvider>
    <App />
  </UserProvider>
</BrowserRouter>
```

</React.StrictMode>